# Resampling raster with categorical data in R?

Tags: raster, r, resampling

I have a covertype raster layer which is categorical data (1,2,3...19), and I want to change its resolution, coordination system, column numbers and row numbers to fit with other raster layers. But after I did the resample with "ngb" method, it turned out to have continuous numbers, instead of discrete numbers.

The code is like:

```
covertype<-brick("/Volumes/Covertype/covertype.tif")
newproj<-"+proj=utm +zone=47 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
covertype1<-projectRaster(covertype, crs=newproj, res=30)
e<-extent(597568.9, 795028.9, 2340412, 2499892)
s<-raster(e, nrows=5316, ncols=6582, crs=newproj)
covertype2<-resample(covertype1, s, method="ngb")
```

I thought using method of "ngb" would not yield numbers different from the original raster layers, but "covertype2" has numbers like 10.00000023.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to use a nearest neighbour method when reprojecting:

```
covertype1<-projectRaster(covertype, crs=newproj, res=30)
```

from `?projectRaster`

```
method: method used to compute values for the new RasterLayer. Either
      'ngb' (nearest neighbor), which is useful for categorical
      variables, or 'bilinear' (bilinear interpolation; the default
      value), which is appropriate for continuous variables.
```

adding `method="ngb"` to your reprojection should fix that.

Answer (score 3):

Without a reproducible example, it is difficult to say but I expect your problem is to do with the data type.

For example:

```
library(raster)

ras1 <- raster(matrix(sample(1:19, 100, replace=T), nrow = 10), ) # Make some example data (10 x 10 px)
ras2 <- raster(matrix(rep(1,16), nrow = 4)) # Make a smaller raster (4 x 4 px)
ras3 <- resample(ras1, ras2, method="ngb")

unique(ras1) # Only whole numbers
unique(ras3) # Only whole numbers
```

This works fine so without knowing more about your file it is difficult to answer.